# Using URLConnetion.getInputStream() to get source code (amazon.de)

Tags: java, urlconnection

When I want to get the source code of a specific web page, I use following code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://google.de");
URLConnection urlConnect = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnect.getInputStream())); //Here is the error with the amazon url
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String line, htmlData;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    sb.append(line+"\n");
}
htmlData = sb.toString();
```

The code above works without problems, **but** when your url is called...

```
URL url = new URL("https://amazon.de");
```

...then you might get sometimes a IOException error -> Server error code 503. In my opinion, this doesn't make any sense, because I can enter the amazon web page with the browser without any errors.

Comment: It works for me with Oracle JDK 8 64 bit.

Comment: it looks like this error is returned from Amazon, not related to your code. your code is doing what you are expecting

Comment: But why you can access the web page with a normal browser and not with this java code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When accessing `https://amazon.de` with `curl -v https://amazon.de` you either get a **503** or a **301** status code in the response (When following the redirect, you get a **503** from the referenced location https://www.amazon.de/). The body contains the following comment:

> To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.
>    For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.de/ref=rm_5_sv, or our Product Advertising API at https://partnernet.amazon.de/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_5_ac for advertising use cases.

I assume Amazon is returning this response when your request is detected as coming from a non browser context (i.e. by parsing the user agent) to hint you towards using the APIs and not crawling the sites directly.